# null value in comparison seems to be not null

Tags: java, android, if-statement, null

Normally I make a comparison in every activity(Android) but I have a problem and I couldn't find the solution. I tried everything I could but result is still the same.

In if statement `null` value seems to be not null.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the code :**

```
System.out.println(item.getSub()); // output is null
if (item.getSub()!=null) {
    r.putExtra("engsub", item.getSub()); // Normally it shouldn't, but it goes in here
    startActivityForResult(r, position); 
}
else {
    //Do something
}
```

**And I tried this :**

```
String def = item.getSub()+"";
System.out.println(def); // output is not null
    if (!def.equals("")) {
    r.putExtra("engsub", item.getSub()); // Normally it shouldn't, but it goes in here
startActivityForResult(r, position); 
}
else {
    //Do something
}
```

**Added :**

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(result);
            asd = new String[5][jsonResponse.length()];
            rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem2>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject js = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                                    // ....codes
                asd[4][i] = js.getString("engsub");;

                item = new RowItem2(asd[0][i], asd[1][i], asd[2[i],
                        asd[3][i],asd[4][i]);
                rowItems.add(item);
            }
```

**RowItem2 class**

```
  private String engsub;
  public RowItem2(String title, String desc,String desc2,String desc3,String engsub) {
    this.engsub = engsub;
   //......
}
  //.......
public String getSub() {
    return engsub;
}
public void setSub(String engsub) {
    this.engsub = engsub;
}
```

Comment: "*output is not null*". What is it, then ?

Comment: Maybe it's a String "null"?

Comment: check `item.getSub()` all time `NULL`

Comment: Kocko : Just empty string -> `""`. If you called it a null it is null. I tried to say not writing `null` in output.

Comment: is `item.getSub()` your own code? Post that code pls.

Comment: `"".equals(string)` ? or `.isEmpty()`?

Comment: I edited my code please look at the new added codes.

Comment: show your JSON string - I think it contains the word "NULL" in it - I've updated my answer with that.

Comment: Remove the Sys out and try. I think this will give you a null in the if statement. Just try it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think JSON string `result` contains the word "NULL" in it.

Look at the docs about [JSONObject on Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Here is the line that solves your problem:

> When the requested type is a String, other non-null values will be
>   coerced using valueOf(Object). Although null cannot be coerced, the
>   sentinel value NULL is coerced to the string "null".

---

Below some ideas when trying to track down an issue like this:

---

### Confirm your assumptions

You sound confused, so set your mind at ease. There is nothing wrong with Java / Android. Confirm this with a change that will work correctly every time.

This change challenges your assumption: you assume that `item.getSub()` is returning `null`.

```
String nullString = null;
System.out.println(nullString);
if (nullString != null) {
    r.putExtra("engsub", item.getSub()); // Normally it shouldn't, but it goes in here
    startActivityForResult(r, position); 
}
else {
    //Do something
}
```

This will NOT pass the `if` test, unless there is something wrong with your IDE.

---

### Confirm your IDE is working

You may still think you are getting `null`. In some cases it could look like this.

Sometimes Eclipse will not put the correct code onto your emulator / device. There could be an issue with the build.

So do a project Clean. Then build again and test.

This will confirm that you are running the correct code.

---

### Confirm what you are seeing

Sometimes when output looks like a "" string, it can be " " or "   ".

Try logging your output surrounded by [ and ].

```
System.out.println("[" + item.getSub() + "]");
```

---

### Look deeper into the code

This is why I asked to see the `item.getSub()` code, and the extra you have shown.

If the above tests don't help, look to see how that value is set / returned.

Looking into [`JSONObject.getString()` javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29), it shows that it cannot return a `null` value:

In your case, log out the JSON string, and log out the values in `RowItem2` constructor.

That should show you the "NULL" I refer to at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried step by step your answers and i found the problem. JSON array value is null but when i get this value it is being string "null". Anyway i solved my problem thank you again.

Comment: @user3583237 glad I could help. These are useful basic debugging steps for all problems you encounter. By following these steps, I came across the JSONObject documentation, which explains how I knew what the problem was. Try to remember these steps in the future, they will help you a lot as you gain experience.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
if (item.getSub() instanceof String) {
    r.putExtra("engsub", item.getSub()); // Normally it shouldn't, but it goes in here
    startActivityForResult(r, position); 
}
else {
    //Do something
}
```

This way you're sure that the item.getSub() is a string.

Comment: yes `item.getSub()` is instanceof String. goes in `if` statmenet

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(!"".equals(your string) 
{
    // do something
}
```